# How to exclude a specific div on 'focus-out' event

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, dom-events

I work on an Ember application, where I have:

1. `{{input type="text" focus-out="inputFocusOut"}}`
2. `<div class="mylist"><u><li action {{action "selectItem" item}}>item</li></ul></div>`

My problem is that when I click on an `<li>` item, the `inputFocusOut` function is executed.

Currently I have `setTimeout` inside the `inputFocusOut` to make it work.

But is there a way to exclude `<div class="mylist">` when the `focus-out` event is triggered ?
So not to be executed when I click on the `<li>`s , maybe?

Comment: Where is the div to be excluded, could you post some more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass focusOut event by adding a `mouseDown` event besides your `click` event to your `li` like this:

```
{{input type="text" focus-out=(action "inputFocusOut") }}
<ul><li {{action "selectItem" item on="click" }} {{action "myMouseDownEvent" item on='mouseDown'}}>{{item}}</li></ul>
```

Checkout [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1ad5d2708834fd8f26d67af31d593abc) for this usage.